# How to check if the service and the server is available?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I would like to check if given server is online and given service is active -- or maybe even simpler, if given port is open.

Something like this:

```
port_check my_server 22
```

or

```
service_check my_server ssh
```

And I would get a binary answer -- yes/no, meaning everything is OK, or there is no connection (server is down, or the service is not active).

I have to run this tool from ordinary user account (non-root). The question is -- what is the tool? Thank you in advance for help.

**Edit**: please note, I have to get binary answer, which means any interactive tool, or tool that tries to log in first is no good. It should be basically a ping but for any service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`telnet` is that tool. `check.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

telnet -e / $1 $2 <<END
/
close
END
echo $?
```

running - `check.sh localhost <port>`

Note that the service listening the port will be touched.

Comment: Either it is not this tool, or I don't know how to use it -- I tried it before asking, but it is interactive. I didn't find any info in manual (man telnet) how to switch it to non-interactive mode.

Comment: Aah, little magic is required ;-) Thank you very much! Now I can run parallel in very nice fashion. Edit: Yes, sure, I have to wait to accept the answer though, SO limitation.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try nmap tool.

the simplest way to use it is `nmap -p$2 $1` but you can alternatively specify a port or even a host range to check.

Comment: This form is OK, thank you. It looks like more specific tool than telnet, but I tried it and I got surprising outcome -- checking google port (80) took 0.3 second for telnet (Khachik's script) while nmap needed about 7 seconds!